# how to rapidly deploy troops in a dispersed area

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've seen it done before where troops are deployed quickly in a line. How is this done? I've tried dragging my finger across the screen but this just scrolls the screen around.

Comment: U can quickly spam enemy bases with barbarians and archers. By rapid deployment

Answer (score 3):

To deploy multiple troops in quick succession you need to press the screen until a troop spawns, then drag your finger across to where you want the rest of your troops to spawn. Do note that sometimes on IOS the multitouch gestures interfers with this functionality and may need to be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I use the multiple troop deploy generally to deploy multiple archers around dragon or other clan castle defending troops.

**To deploy several units** :

1) zoom up to the area u want to deploy.( only if your screen is small I.e. about 5 inch).

2) make sure that about 4 fingers would be able to touch the deploying area.

3) press and hold your finger(s) for deployment.

**Caution** : if 3 - 5 fingers are used the available troop count will decrease drastically

**Advantages:**

By the time a defence tries to kill one troop ,(assuming you have deployed many troops at a time by multi touch) the troop spawned with victim troop gets little more time to attack.